# Springfox-Swagger2 406 not acceptable error -Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox, http-status-code-406

Hi I am getting "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers" error i.e Http 406 not acceptable.

I am using the below dependencies for swagger

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

My swagger config file is as below

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Component
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin() {

        ArrayList<ResponseMessage> standardExpectedHttpResponses =
                createStandardExpectedHttpResponses();

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,
                        standardExpectedHttpResponses)
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST,
                        standardExpectedHttpResponses)
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.PUT,
                        standardExpectedHttpResponses)
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.DELETE,
                        standardExpectedHttpResponses)
                /*.globalOperationParameters((List<Parameter>) new ParameterBuilder()
                        .name("xyz=id")
                        .description("Description of someGlobalParameter")
                        .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                        .parameterType("query")
                        .required(true)
                        .build())*/
                .produces(createStandardProducesConsumes())
                .consumes(createStandardProducesConsumes()).pathMapping("")
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                        .basePackage("com.x.y.z"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/*"))
                .build().apiInfo(metadata());
    }

    private ApiInfo metadata() {

        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API - xyz")
                .description(
                        "This is a Swagger-enabled API representation for the xyz.")
                .version("1.0").build();
    }

    private ArrayList<ResponseMessage> createStandardExpectedHttpResponses() {
        ArrayList<ResponseMessage> messages = new ArrayList<ResponseMessage>();

        messages.add(new ResponseMessage(200, "Ok", null));
        messages.add(new ResponseMessage(400, "Bad Request", null));
        messages.add(new ResponseMessage(401, "Unauthorized", null));
        messages.add(new ResponseMessage(403, "Forbidden", null));
        messages.add(new ResponseMessage(404, "Not Found", null));
        messages.add(new ResponseMessage(500, "Internal Server Error", null));

        return messages;
    }

    private HashSet<String> createStandardProducesConsumes() {
        HashSet<String> producesConsumes = new HashSet<String>();

        producesConsumes.add("application/json");

        return producesConsumes;
    }
}
```

Also CORS filter is setup for the project. Anything is missing ? How do i resolve this.

When i hit the service it is giving me the response. It is working fine. I dont have to add any request parameters. Above link is giving me the response.

When I hit http://localhost:8080/endpoint/v2/api-docs, I have the http 406 error. Do i need to add any annotations to my service ?

Comment: Can you post your CORS Filter ?
I had a similar problem because I did not set all the response headers in my CORS Filter. And try to upgrade your swagger dependency. I use version 2.5.0. (And I just see that version 2.6.1 is released)

Comment: Sure .. Thank you for the response. Below is my CORS filter.

Comment: I have added the CORS filter as below

Comment: Am i missing something in cors filter ?

Answer (score 0):

I have commented below code in my Servlet. It started working.

```
<util:map id="mediaTypesMapping">
      <!--   <entry key="text/plain" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
        <entry key="text/html" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <entry key="application/json" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8" />
        <entry key="application/xml" value="application/xml;charset=UTF-8" />
        <entry key="jsonp" value="application/javascript" />
        <entry key="application/javascript" value="application/javascript" />
        <entry key="application/x-protobuf" value="application/x-protobuf" /> -->
        <entry key="application/json" value="application/json" />
    </util:map>
```

My Service URL is
http://localhost:8080/endpoint
My Swagger UI is adding param name to URL. How do i change this ?

URL produced by my swagger UI is after passing query param

http://localhost:8090/rendpoint?allRequestParams=q%3Did%3A*%26fl%3Did